# Apply a sequence based on the value of another column

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a sequence that starts with 1000 and increments by one unit. Then, apply this sequence to the variable "identification" of my table "person". The number of records in the table "person" is 958, so it should increment to the end by default. In addition, I want the numbering to be based on the Age field sorted in descending order. It's to say: the field 'Identification' has no records, it has NULL values. When I say sort by age, I mean that the one with the youngest age will be assigned the ID number 1000, the second youngest will be assigned 1001 and so on.

I have tried to do something similar to the following but I get no results. I have also tried to put an order by age desc in the middle of the sentence also without result. Any idea to do it only using sequences please?

```
TABLE PERSON (Name, Surname, City, Identification, Age)

CREATE SEQUENCE seq 
START WITH 1000
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1000;

ALTER TABLE person
ADD COLUMN identification integer DEFAULT nextval('seq');
```

Comment: Not going to happen. [Sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) don't work that way. They are meant to just generate numbers, potentially with gaps. If you want to do this you will have to create your own procedure.

Comment: Hi! @AdrianKlaver Then I could solve it with some other SQL statement such as a function? How do you think would be the easiest way?

Comment: Since I am not following your reasoning I can't really offer a solution. 1) Not sure why you want the 'order by age', there will no doubt be many people of the same name so sequential numbers will not mean much. 2) Do the existing records already have `Identification` numbers? 3) If not why do want to start with 1000? To your question add a more complete description of what you want to do and why?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Well that is the context of the problem. The field 'Identification' has no records, it has NULL values. When I say sort by age, I mean that the one with the youngest age will be assigned the ID number 1000, the second youngest will be assigned 1001 and so on.  On the other hand, there are no people with the same age, therefore, there would be no problems regarding this last aspect.

Comment: Add the context to your question so others don't have to dig through the comments for relevant information. Also is this a one time operation or will rows be added to the table over time?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes you're right I'll edit the post. And yes is a one time operation

Comment: I believe this '...Age field sorted in descending order' is supposed to be 'Age field sorted in ascending order'.

Comment: Well..the concept is a bit confusing, but I mean that it will first assign 1000 to the one with age 1, 1001 to the one with age 2, 1002 to the one with age 3 and so on. Therefore, I said descending

Comment: Moving from 1 --> 2 --> 3 and 1001 --> 1002 --> 1003 is ascending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick example using dummy data:

```
create table age_seq_test(age int , fld_1 varchar, id integer);

insert into age_seq_test values (10, 'test'), (30, 'test2'), (20, 'test3');

select * from age_seq_test order by age;
 age | fld_1 |  id  
-----+-------+------
  10 | test  | NULL
  30 | test2 | NULL
  20 | test3 | NULL

BEGIN;

with t as 
   (select age, row_number() over (order by age) as rn from age_seq_test) 
update 
    age_seq_test AS ast 
set 
    id = t.rn + 999
from 
    t 
where  
    ast.age = t.age  ;

select * from age_seq_test order by age;
 age | fld_1 |  id  
-----+-------+------
  10 | test  | 1000
  20 | test3 | 1001
  30 | test2 | 1002


--COMMIT/ROLLBACK depending on what the SELECT shows.
```